# Sort parent user list by inner hits elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have 200K users in elasticsearch and each user has its own inbox. Now suppose threeo users user A,B and C. User A and user C send message to user B. So when user B fetch users list from elasticsearch then user A and C should be on the top of the user list because A and B most recent sent message to user B. I write my elasticsearch query that is given below

```
{
  "_source": [
    "db_id",
    "username",
    "message_privacy"
  ],
  "from": "0",
  "size": "40",
  "sort": [{"messages_received.created_at" : "desc"}],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
           "term":{
             "type":"user"
           }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "messages_received",
            "inner_hits": {
              "sort": [
                {
                  "created_at": "desc"
                }
              ],
              "size": 1,
              "_source": [
                "id",
                "user_id",
                "object_id",
                "created_at"
              ]
            },
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "object_id": "u-5"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run query it gives me error

> {   "error": {
>       "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "query_shard_exception",
>           "reason": "No mapping found for [messages_received.created_at] in order to sort on",
>           "index_uuid": "5jsM1khYRrC0cjWbRjsx5A",
>           "index": "trending"
>         }
>       ],

I search this problem on google but not usefull solution found for my scenario.

Mapping

```
{
 "type": {
            "type": "join",
            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
            "relations": {
              "post": [
                "comments",
                "place",
                "media",
                "views",
                "likes",
                "post_box"
              ],
              "box": "posts",
              "user": [
                "user_views",
                "user_likes",
                "followers",
                "post",
                "blocked",
                "followings",
                "box",
                "block",
                "notifications",
                "messages_received",
                "messages_sent"
              ],
              "posts": "posts_views"
            }
          }}
```